How to define contour levels is irregular intervals for a contour plot type “level” - Plotly
i have same problem like this thread https://community.plotly.com/t/custom-contour-levels-for-a-contour-plot
The problem is : Is there a definitive way to plot custom contour levels yet? I’m attempting to plot some precipitation data and therefore need irregular intervals. If not, how would I go about this using traces?
Go to detail, i have the : percentile_array = [0, 25, 40, 55, 75, 90, 97, 100], then i find value that be long to these percentile like this : levels = np.percentile(np.array(z), percentile_array ) ;
How to i define level for a contour plot type “level” by levels that is irregular intervals ?
Thank you very much!
I did :
levels: number[] = [
  4.8314418161055977e-107, 0.0000017463453954373618, 0.000014846860866444588,
  0.000027149482898503123, 0.000044051660141765534, 0.0000653088414811442, 0.00009377625365944794,
  0.0003483965420565838,
];

contours: {
        start: levels[0],
        end: levels[levels.length -1],
        size: levels[1] - levels[0],
      },

I expect 6 level with contour line but that did not run as my expect.
